# how to determine the number of unique values based on multiple criteria dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, unique

I've got a df that looks like:

df(site=c(A,B,C,D,E), species=c(1,2,3,4), Year=c(1980:2010).

I would like to calculate the number of different years that each species appear in each site, creating a new column called nYear, I've tried filtering by group and using mutate combined with ndistinct values but it is not quite working.

Here is part of the code I have been using:

```
Df1 <- Df %>%
  filter(Year>1985)%>%
  mutate(nYear = n_distinct(Year[Year %in% site]))%>%
  group_by(Species,Site, Year) %>% 
  arrange(Species, .by_group=TRUE) 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is good, a few things to correct.

First, let's make some reproducible data (your code gave errors).

```
df <- data.frame("site"=LETTERS[1:5], "species"=1:5, "Year"=1981:2010)
```

You should have used `summarise` instead of `mutate` when you're looking to summarise values across groups. It will give you a shortened `tibble` as an output, with only the groups and the summary figures present (fewer columns and rows).

`mutate` on the other hand aims to modify an existing `tibble`, keeping all rows and columns by default.

The order of your functions in the chains also needs to change.

```
df %>%
  filter(Year>1985) %>%
  group_by(species,site) %>% 
  summarise(nYear = length(unique(Year))) %>% # instead of mutate
  arrange(species, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
ungroup()
```

First, `group_by(species,site)`, not year, then `summarise` and `arrange`.

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  species site  nYear
    <int> <chr> <int>
1       1 A         5
2       2 B         5
3       3 C         5
4       4 D         5
5       5 E         5
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked and provided the information I was looking to get, however, summarise, as you said, gives a shortened version of my original df, but I would like to keep all the colums in my dataset. I've tried using mutate as per my original question, is there any simple way to keep all columns?

Comment: I would suggest to create a new question in order to detail which error you're getting using `mutate`. You can comment here the link to this new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235302/cumulative-sum-of-unique-values-based-on-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct()` on the filtered frame, and then count by your groups of interest:

```
distinct(Df %>% filter(Year>1985)) %>%
  count(Site, Species,name = "nYear")
```

Comment: this works well indeed. Counting *unique* values even in the presence of other columns in the data.

Comment: my solution may be more concise and computationally faster, but you (+1) have provided a more thorough explanation to help the OP understand their approach

Comment: Thanks I tried this and also worked great!